# Crossfilter group to ignore several filters

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

In the [Crossfilter API](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group-map-reduce) it is stated that when creating a group from a `dimension`, it doesn't take into account the filter applied to this `dimension`. Is it possible in some way to create a group ignoring filters on several dimensions, instead of just one?

---

**For example:**
I have 3 dimensions on which a user can filter `population` instances: `Planet`, `Country`, and `City`. When setting filters on each of the dimensions, the `population` entries should satisfy all the filters, like it does by default. But there should also be an interface where a user can define filters on each dimension. And considering this hierarchy, selecting certain `City` should not limit the list of available `Country` or `Planet` choices. But selecting a certain `Planet` should limit the list of available `Country` and `City` choices. Can it be done by means of Groups in Crossfilter.js?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is currently a way to do this, and I do see the attraction, but I'm not sure the use-case really ends up being realistic. Meaning, if you select a certain city, say "Berlin", then why wouldn't the list of available Countries be restricted to those that have a city named "Berlin"? Likewise for Planet?

If you want to open an issue at https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter to discuss further and work out some examples, that would probably be the place to do it.